# Getting "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated", exception in .NET Corel

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, predicate

I am working on a C# application. I have to create a predicate for filtering data. I have a model class `TissueItem` which has a property named `ExpirationData`. I have to get that data from `TissueItem` where expiration date is less than or equal to number specified. My predicate expression is:

```cs
ExpressionStarter<TissueItem> predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<TissueItem>();
predicate = predicate.And(x => 
    Convert.ToInt32((x.ExpirationDate.Value - DateTime.Today).TotalDays) 
       <= inventorySearchFilterModel.ExpirationStatus);
```

When i pass this predicate to get the data, i am getting the following exception:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TissueItem>()
    .Where(t => Convert.ToInt32((t.ExpirationDate.Value - DateTime.Today).TotalDays) <= __inventorySearchFilterModel_ExpirationStatus_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

What can be the possible issue. I am using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ expression error could not be translated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248564/linq-expression-error-could-not-be-translated)

Comment: @YegorAndrosov nops

Comment: Even if i remove "Convert.ToInt32", it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant. Looks like EFC do not handle `Timestamp.TotalDays`.

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<TissueItem>();
predicate = predicate.And(x => 
    EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.ExpirationDate.Value, DateTime.Today) 
       <= inventorySearchFilterModel.ExpirationStatus);
```

Comment: Already tried that. Its still not working . . . By the exception message, i think this functionality can not be achieved at EF level. May be have to apply date filter after receiving the data from database (at client side) @Svyatoslav Danyliv .. .  I am not sure about this client side filtering, it just what i understood up till now.

Comment: It should work. Probably you have not shown whole scenario. Try without PredicateBuilder.